# Printer unable to use Gmail SMTP server

Tags: email, gmail, network-printer, smtp

I've been following [this Google Apps support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) to be able to set up scan-to-email using the Gmail SMTP server. The printer is a [Samsung CLX-6260 FW](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/CLX-6260FW/XAA).

I've configured it with the following information:

> SMTP Server: `smtp.gmail.com`
>   Port Number: `465`
>   SMTP Requires Authentication: `Yes`
>   - Login ID: `<my Google Apps email>`
>   - Password: `<my Google Apps email password>`
>   Secure E-Mail Connection with SSL/TLS: `Enabled`
>   SMTP Server Connection Timeout: `30`

But whenever I test the connection, it fails with a server timeout. I've tried increasing the connection timeout limit, but that doesn't seem to work. Has anyone managed to set this up successfully? How did you do it?

**UPDATE:** I tried out port 587 and that started working. Haven't gotten around to testing with a VPS, but the output of `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465` shows that the connection *does* work from our network, so if anyone out there knows what the answer might be, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: You may want to check if your ISP is blocking port 25.

Comment: Do you have a linux VPS you can use for testing? I'd try listening with netcat, something like `nc -vv -l 465`, then configure the printer to connect to your VPS instead of Google's mail server. This could help to confirm if there's a routing problem.

Comment: I had a similar question. It seems that Gmail only allows OAuth 2.0 authentication, but you can enable other methods in account settings. http://superuser.com/questions/987842/why-can-i-authenticate-to-my-gmail-account-neither-from-my-printer-nor-from-my

Comment: Did you enable "unsecure" or "insecure" apps through the gmail web interface?

Answer (score 2):

If possible, try changing the Scanners network configuration to use Google's DNS servers.

- Set the preferred DNS as 8.8.8.8
- Set the alternate DNS as 8.8.4.4

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work :(